# after edit workflow state does not reset?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

I've implemented a sitecore workflow *identical* to [this one](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/09/publish-to-pre-production-web-database.html); basically i have two databases (staging web and production web) and two approved states for each database, one of them final, the other semi-final.

This works good for new items, but when i change a field in an item that is already in the 'Approved for Production' state, it will not reset back to draft, as it's supposed to.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you logged in with a user who has Admin right? Administrators bypass security and workflow.

Comment: yes i am - will try with an user with lesser permissions

Comment: You should indeed try this with a user that does not have the rights on that particular workflow step.